# Как в QtCreator заполнить statusbar?

Tags: qt, c++11, qtcreator

Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку statusbar начинал заполняться.
Как мне изменять значение statusbar’а в своей программе?
(C++)

[image]

Comment: казнить нельзя помиловать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните свой вопрос. Хотя бы расставьте знаки препинания, чтобы можно было понять, в чём заключается вопрос.

Comment: @Анастасия так лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посылать сигналы на слот задающий ui->progressBar->setValue(value);